# Are there any mathematical discoveries that are considered trivial or useless?

Tags: philosophy

Are there any mathematical discoveries that are considered trivial or useless? And if that's the case, how do you know if they are trivial or useless? I am asking this question, because I am wondering if imaginary numbers were considered useless for so long why we didn't completely ignore it and decided to forget it was ever discovered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Useless math that became useful](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260877/useless-math-that-became-useful)

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Trivial examples are my favorite because they're very easy. I've certainly discovered some useless things in my spare time and I expect they will always remain useless.